Issues with Maintaining Plot Dimensions using `gt::gtsave()` in R
I have been generating tables using my own function in R and saving them with gt::gtsave(). Previously, I was able to save the output in the desired dimensions, but recently, the saved tables are not maintaining the same size and aspect ratio. Here’s the relevant part of my code:
dplyr::mutate(
  virus_full,
  virus_type = forcats::fct_relevel(virus_type, "WPV1")
) |>
  polioanalytica::create_gt_table(
    drop_date_col = FALSE
  ) |>
  gt::gtsave(
    paste0(plots_path, "/overview_table.png"),
    vwidth = 3650, vheight = 1800
  )

This code used to produce a table image with correct dimensions similar to this screenshot. However, now the output looks more like this one, with the layout compressed and the dimensions not preserved.
With no success, I’ve tried adjusting the vwidth, vheight, expand and zoom parameters in gt::gtsave(). As well as ensuring no changes have been made to my package that could affect table rendering - table looks good when plotting in rstudio.
Questions:
•   What might be causing the saved table to not maintain the correct dimensions?
•   Are there any specific settings or parameters within gt::gtsave() that I should consider adjusting?
•   Could this be related to changes in the underlying gt package, and if so, how can I address it?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

This seems to be an underlying issue with webshot2? https://github.com/rstudio/webshot2/issues/66

As @andy-baxter mentioned in the comments above, the issue appears to be related to the webshot2 package. To work around this, I saved my table as an HTML file first and then captured it as an image using webshot. Here’s the code I used:
# Create and save the table in HTML format
dplyr::mutate(
  virus_full,
  virus_type = forcats::fct_relevel(virus_type, "WPV1")
) |>
  polioanalytica::create_gt_table(
    drop_date_col = FALSE,
    table_fontsize = 24
  ) |>
  gt::gtsave(
    paste0(plots_path, "/overview_table.html")
  )

# Capture the HTML table as a PNG image
webshot::webshot(
  paste0(plots_path, "/overview_table.html"),
  paste0(plots_path, "/overview_table.png"),
  vheight = 1800, 
  vwidth = 3650
)

